# Unit testing spring mvc controller with mockito

Tags: spring, unit-testing, mockito, spring-mvc-test

i'm using mockito and junit and run unit test against spring mvc
my flow of code is:

`Service Layer` -> `Model Layer` -> `Controller Layer`

i was **successfully** testing the Controller against the model layer with the code:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class HashLinkerControllerTest {

private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger
        .getLogger(HashLinkerControllerTest.class);



@Mock
private HashLinkerModel modelMock;

@InjectMocks
private HashLinkerController controller;

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Before
public void setup() {

    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller).build();

}

  @Test
public void update() throws Exception {
    int date = 123;
    String hashToCheck = "asdfasdfasdfasdfas";
    HashLinker first = this.createHashLinker(hashToCheck, "some name",
            "some des", "some data", date);

    when(modelMock.update(first)).then(returnsFirstArg());
    mockMvc.perform(
            put("/api/hashService/" + hashToCheck)
                    .contentType(TestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                    .content(
                            TestUtil.convertObjectToJsonBytesWithSettersOnly(first))
                    .accept(TestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(
                    content().contentType(TestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.hash", is(hashToCheck)))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.description", is("some des")))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.name", is("some name")));

    verify(modelMock, times(1)).update(first);
    verifyNoMoreInteractions(modelMock);
}
```

but now i'm looking for  a way to test the 3 layers structure. i.e testing the service against the controller . i came up with :

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class HashLinkerControllerServiceLayerTest {

private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger
        .getLogger(HashLinkerControllerServiceLayerTest.class);

@Mock
private HashLinkerService serviceMock;

@InjectMocks
// @Mock
private HashLinkerModel modelMock;

private HashLinkerController controller;

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Before
public void setup() {

    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    controller = new HashLinkerController(modelMock);
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller).build();

}
```

and doing the test with

```
@Test
public void update() throws Exception {
    int date = 123;
    String hashToCheck = "asdfasdfasdfasdfas";
    HashLinker first = this.createHashLinker(hashToCheck, "some name",
            "some des", "some data", date);

    when(serviceMock.update(first)).then(returnsFirstArg());
    mockMvc.perform(
            put("/api/hashService/" + hashToCheck)
                    .contentType(TestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                    .content(
                            TestUtil.convertObjectToJsonBytesWithSettersOnly(first))
                    .accept(TestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(
                    content().contentType(TestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.hash", is(hashToCheck)))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.description", is("some des")))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.name", is("some name")));

    verify(serviceMock, times(1)).update(first);
    verifyNoMoreInteractions(serviceMock);
}
```

the test is the same as above expect i have changed `modelMock` to be `serviceMock`. for some reason this test fails . i get 404.
any ideas?

`version:`

`<spring.core.version>3.2.6.RELEASE</spring.core.version>`
`<spring.test.version>3.2.6.RELEASE</spring.test.version>`
`<mockito.version>1.9.5</mockito.version>`
`<junit.version>4.8.2</junit.version>`

**EDIT**:

```
@Component
public class HashLinkerModel {

private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(HashLinkerModel.class);

HashLinkerService service;

/** The unicode service. */
UnicodeService unicodeService;

@Autowired
public HashLinkerModel(HashLinkerService service, UnicodeService unicodeService){
    this.service = service;
    this.unicodeService = unicodeService;

}




     /**
 * check if hash exists before creation
 * @param toHash
 * @return
 */
private HashLinker checkAndcreate(HashLinker toHash){


    String hash = this.createHash(toHash.getData());
    toHash.setHash(hash);

    LOGGER.info("add " + hash + ". this is the hash of string " + toHash.getData());

    /* if this hash already in system. return null. otherwise create */
    HashLinker exists =  service.findByHash(toHash.getHash());

    if (null != exists) 
        return exists;
//** we use service here ** 
    return service.create(toHash);
}

public HashLinker create(HashLinker entity) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    RestPreconditions.checkRequestElementNotNull(entity, LOGGER);
    RestPreconditions.checkRequestElementNotNull(entity.getData(), LOGGER);

    String uniName = getUniHelper().unicode(entity.getName());
    String uniDesc = getUniHelper().unicode(entity.getDescription());

    HashLinker toHash = new HashLinker();
    toHash.setData(entity.getData());

    toHash.setType(entity.getType());

    String baseURL = entity.getBaseURL();

    if (null != baseURL) 
            baseURL  = (baseURL.length() > HashLinker.getIntMaxBaseURL()) ? baseURL.substring(0, HashLinker.getIntMaxBaseURL()) : baseURL;

    toHash.setBaseURL(baseURL);
    toHash.setStatus(0);
    // update lecker's macros results
    toHash.setName(uniName);
    toHash.setDescription(uniDesc);


    return checkAndcreate(toHash);

}
```

Comment: Show us how `HashLinkerModel` is using `HashLinkerService.update(first)`

Comment: @MariuszS i added the relevant hashLinkerModel code. thanks

Comment: Thanks, but in this code `HashLinkerService.update(first)` is never executed, maybe this is the problem. Also `modelMock.update(first)` is not visible here, looks like this code is unrelated to unit test. Show me your `update()` method.

Comment: update does get fire. from `checkAndCreate` that gets fire from `create`

Answer (score 1):

Put your line

```
verify(serviceMock, times(1)).update(first);
```

after

```
mockMvc.perform(
        put("/api/hashService/" + hashToCheck)
                .contentType(TestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .content(
                        TestUtil.convertObjectToJsonBytesWithSettersOnly(first))
                .accept(TestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8));
```

but before mockMvc assertions, to verify that your mock is used.

General issues with your code:

- With annotation `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` initializing Mockito manually is not necessary.

  > **@MockitoJUnitRunner**
  >
  > Initializes mocks annotated with Mock, so that explicit usage of **MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(Object)** is not necessary.
- Unit testing

  > i'm looking for a way to test the 3 layers structure.

  When  three layers are involved in the test, the test is an **integration test**.
- In unit testing it is better to have many small method for testing different behaviour. So one method should test HTTP Response, second should verify if service is invoked.

Comment: thanks for the tips. tried the put `verify` statement after perform. service doesn't get called. infact i get error of  404.  which means something with the controller doesn't work properly, isn't ? maybe my 3rd layer structure for how to init the test are not allowed with spring ?

Comment: @oak We need more data, Show us `HashLinkerModel` and `HashLinkerService`