# Junit4 Mockito UnfinishedVerificationException TransactionManager

Tags: mockito, junit4, spring-4, transactionmanager

i'm just running into a complicated Problem as i began to unit-Test some Controller-Methods in a Spring FW4 based Java Application.

My ApplicationConfig.java is annotated with @Configuration and @EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass = true) and a public Controller method, which i created to save a new object of a simple entity-class is testet with the following ControllerTestClass

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:/test-context.xml"})
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true, transactionManager = "annotationDrivenTransactionManager")
public class TestController 
    @Autowired
    public MyClassService myClassServiceMock;

    protected MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    protected WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
    };

    @org.junit.Before
    public void reset() {
        Mockito.reset(myClassServiceMock);
    }

    @org.junit.After
    public void after() { 
         verifyNoMoreInteractions(myClassServiceMock);
    }


    @Test
    public void testSaveObject() throws Exception {
        MyObject object = new MyObjectBuilder().withName("object").withDate("2014-08-15").build();
        when(myClassServiceMock.createObject(objectName, objectDate)).thenReturn(object);

        [.. mockMvcTest which works ... ]

        verify(myclassServiceMock, times(1)).createObject(objectName, objectDate);
    }
}
```

The following part of the debug.log is something I can't figure out the reason for the problem, but when i remove the @EnableTransactionManager-Annotation, no error occures...

```
2014-08-15_17:25:59.608 [main] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Creating new transaction with name [a.b.c.MyClassService$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$cf62a86c.saveObject]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
2014-08-15_17:25:59.608 [main] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Opened new EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@513f39c] for JPA transaction
2014-08-15_17:25:59.616 [main] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC transaction [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@320cac01]
2014-08-15_17:25:59.618 [main] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Initiating transaction commit
2014-08-15_17:25:59.618 [main] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@513f39c]
2014-08-15_17:25:59.633 [main] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Closing JPA EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@513f39c] after transaction
2014-08-15_17:25:59.633 [main] DEBUG o.s.o.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils - Closing JPA EntityManager
2014-08-15_17:25:59.635 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.c.s.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener - After test method: context [DefaultTestContext@8f72029 testClass = MyControllerTest, testInstance = a.b.c.MyControllerTest@453204e6, testMethod = testSaveObject@MyClassControllerTest, testException = org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedVerificationException: 
Missing method call for verify(mock) here:
-> at a.b.c.MyClassService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$809f2bf.invoke(<generated>)

Example of correct verification:
    verify(mock).doSomething()
```

I would really appreciate some help, because my oddisee and research already is going on for a couple of days :(

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you aren't initializing Mockito in your tests. [Read this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21216349/unit-testing-spring-mvc-controller-with-mockito)

You need to call `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks()` because you are already using `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` and you can only specify one runner on a Class.

```
@Before
public void reset() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    // Mockito.reset(myClassServiceMock);   <= remove this line
}
```

I think you also want to use @Mock instead of @Autowired for this mock so that you have an instance of a Mockito mock that you can then call `verify()` on later. You will also have to inject `myClassServiceMock` into your class under test (i.e. the Controller)

```
@Mock
public MyClassService myClassServiceMock;
```

You can remove the call to Mockito.reset() as @Mock will create a new instance for each test method.

If you were intending to use `@Autowired` and retrieve the instance of MyClassService from your application context then you won't be able to call any Mockito methods like verify() on it.

I would also expect that `@TransactionConfiguration` is not required because you are never hitting your database (because you are mocking out your service layer), so you can remove it. If you are hitting your database in your test, then that's a different story, but I can't tell that from the code you have provided.

Comment: That is really helping me out, my friend! Thank you! I am a huge newbie to JUnit and i was used to work with great test-developers so far. Now it is my turn to gain some experience.

I got your points and understood from Mockito Documentation, why it is making my life easier. But let me ask, what do you mean by:"You will also have to inject myClassServiceMock into your class under test (i.e. the Controller)"? Work with @Inject?

Comment: Assuming the controller class you are testing is called `MyController` then I would expect your test to inject `myClassServiceMock` that was created by @Mock. How is MyController obtaining it's reference to MyClassService? Does it query it from the Application Context directly, or is it @Autowired?

Comment: MockitoAnnotations.initMocks()
This line doesn't initialize mockito, it just find all annotations and inject mocked object to all @Mock fields. You can use Mockito.mock() instead of annotations